# NewtonSoft PreserveReferenceHandling: $id property standards, override value generation

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

If your object being serialized is marked with `[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]` it will be serialized with an `$id` property, which will consist of an incremented integer value for each distinct object reference in the graph of objects being serialized.

But if the objects are serialized independently, joined together, and then deserialized (aka: chatty GET, chunky POST/PUT), these values need to be re-keyed, or errors will be thrown on deserialization and the resulting graph will be incomplete as 'duplicate' references will be ignored.

In most cases though, objects already have their own unique IDs (ie: guids).

I've worked around this in 2 ways:

1. Turn off reference preservation, and
2. Add a dummy property to the object which merely exposes the native ID, and decorating it with `[JsonProperty("$id")]`

And while I don't currently care about reference counting, I may in the future, but I don't like having duplicate properties in my resulting JSON for the same guid value.

**So I'm wondering if there is a way to force NewtonSoft to use the `id` property already on my object in place of the `$id` property?**

[ Alternatively, I could mark the object's ID property with `[JsonProperty("$id")]` and change all JSON-consuming code to use that `$id` property instead of `id` .. but I just don't like that idea.. However, if `$ref` and `$id` are JSON standards (are they?) and client frameworks do not gracefully try to use `id` in the place of absent `$id` (should I care?), my only option is basically duplicate properties or forcing all consuming code to use `$id`. ]

**If I can't (or shouldn't) change the property used for reference tracking, are there any reasons why forcing a Guid into the `$id` property is equally bad form? (ie: If there is a reasonable standard for this, does it dictate numeric-only data for the value?)**

Thanks

Comment: I exactly have the same issue, but I do not know how others solved it. I actually wrote a javascript method that ensures unique $id and also changes the $ref accordingly.

Comment: hmm. would you be willing to share that code as an answer? ;)